# Multi-dimensional theorem of calculus as a multidimensional integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convolution, multiple-integral

As indicated in the title, I am looking for a multi-dimensional version of the theorem of calculus that I think to already have seen before but I cannot remember where. What I remember is something looking like
$$f(x) - f(y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \frac{(x-y)·∇f(z)}{|x-z|^d} \,\mathrm{d}\,z.$$
Is this formula true? Or something in the same spirit? What would be the proof?

Thank you.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Gauss theorem is the proper generalization of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: So, to be a little more precise, I am looking at a formula for $f(x)-f(y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $f$ is scalar-valued.
Gauss theorem (Or Stokes, Green, etc) are a good generalization of the fundamental theorem as ways to express the integral of a differential form in terms of a contour. Here I am looking for the way to express the difference $f(x)-f(y)$ as an integral over $\mathbb{R}^d$.

A formula with a 1-dimensional integral is
$$f(x)-f(y) = \int_0^1 (x-y)·∇f((1-t)x+ty)\,\mathrm{d}t$$

Comment: Here, I am looking for a formula with a multi-dimensional integral instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was not far, the formula I was looking for was
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{|\mathbb{S}^{d-1}|} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \frac{\left(x-y\right)·\nabla f(y)}{|x-y|^d}\,\mathrm{d}y.
$$

This follows from
$$
f = -\Delta(-\Delta)^{-1}f = -\nabla\cdot\left(\frac{1}{(2-d)\,|\mathbb{S}^{d-1}|\,|x|^{d-2}} * ∇f\right) = \frac{1}{|\mathbb{S}^{d-1}|}\frac{x}{|x|^{d}}*∇f
$$

Answer (score 1):

The given formula is incorrect. I will prove by giving a counter example.

Let $f(z)=z_1$ then the gradient is $\nabla f \equiv e_1$.
Let $y=0$.

Insert into the given formula
\begin{align}
  f(x)-f(y)=x_1 \overset{?}{=} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{(x-y)\cdot \nabla f (z)}{|x-z|^n} \, dz
  = x_1 \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{|x-z|^n} \, dz
  = x_1 \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{|z|^n} \, dz
\end{align}

The last integral is not unity for standard 3-dimensional space and also not for other dimensions.
This is obvious using [multidimensional spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_volume_and_area_elements).

Comment: Yes, the last integral here is infinite.